# Как объединить аккаунты пользователя на моём сайте/ВКонтакте/Facebook?

Tags: mysql, vkontakte-api

Есть регистрация на сайте: пользователю присваивается ID и все действия идут от этого ID.
Хочу подключить также авторизацию от ВКонтакте и Facebook.

Как мне собрать это в кучу, чтобы один пользователь мог работать сперва через аккаунт моего сайта, затем через аккаунт ВКонтакте, и иметь при этом централизованные данные?

Как это делается?
Спасибо.

Comment: можно использовать подход so: 1) регистрируемся через сайт, либо соцсеть, 2) затем в профиле добавляем возможность привязать другие соцсети, 3) добавляем возможность объединения двух уже существующих на сайте пользователей (на so это вроде в ручном режиме проходит, но вы можете и автоматически это сделать). Тогда "объединение" проходит именно тогда, когда пользователь привязывает соцсеть. Т.е. если тот же пользователь вошел с другой соцсети без привязки или объединения, то это будет другой пользователь.

Comment: у каждой соцсети для каждого пользователя есть свой uid, поэтому можно связывать пользователей по этому uid (email и прочее может быть утеряно/изменено). Только стоит помнить, что разные соцсети могут генерировать один и тот же uid, поэтому связка должна быть `соцсеть; uid`

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете посмотреть, как это сделано на [vhod.cc](http://vhod.cc/). Через какую бы соцсеть - ВКонтакте, Фейсбук, Одноклассники - ни произвел регистрацию пользователь, для него создается учетная запись (очевидно, с внутренним айди). Затем, если пользователь входит еще через одну соцсеть, ее учетные данные добавляются к существующему пользователю (при условии, что человек в этот момент залогинен). Однако если он сначала зарегистрировался, допустим, через ВК, потом вышел и зарегистрировался через Фейсбук, то будут созданы два пользователя. И вот когда он войдет через оба сайта, будет понятно, что это один и тот же человек. Тогда профили просто объединятся без лишних вопросов.

Суть в том, чтобы создавать учетную запись сразу с возможностью добавления в нее идентификаторов всех возможных поставщиков авторизации.